# How to get all combination for a given sum with a given number of elements

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a list of list of floats like this

```
numbers = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
```

I want a python code that can generate all possible combinations for given sum (=1) and a given number of element, for example :

```
numbers = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
sum = 1 
number of elements = 3
```

***outputs :***

```
[(0.1, 0.1, 0.8), (0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0.1, 0.3, 0.6), (0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.1, 0.5, 0.4), (0.1, 0.6, 0.3), (0.1, 0.7, 0.2), (0.1, 0.8, 0.1), (0.2, 0.1, 0.7), (0.2, 0.2, 0.6), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0.2, 0.4, 0.4), (0.2, 0.5, 0.3), (0.2, 0.6, 0.2), (0.2, 0.7, 0.1), (0.3, 0.1, 0.6), (0.3, 0.2, 0.5), (0.3, 0.3, 0.4), (0.3, 0.4, 0.3), (0.3, 0.5, 0.2), (0.3, 0.6, 0.1), (0.4, 0.1, 0.5), (0.4, 0.2, 0.4), (0.4, 0.3, 0.3), (0.4, 0.4, 0.2), (0.4, 0.5, 0.1), (0.5, 0.1, 0.4), (0.5, 0.2, 0.3), (0.5, 0.3, 0.2), (0.5, 0.4, 0.1), (0.6, 0.1, 0.3), (0.6, 0.2, 0.2), (0.6, 0.3, 0.1), (0.7, 0.1, 0.2), (0.7, 0.2, 0.1), (0.8, 0.1, 0.1)]
```

Comment: so what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple approach is to use `itertools.combinations` to generate all the possible combinations, and select those that produce the desired sum.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> numbers = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9]
>>> target_sum = 1
>>> number = 3
>>> [c for c in itertools.combinations(numbers, number) if sum(c) == target_sum]
[(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0.1, 0.3, 0.6), (0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5)]
```

If you want all the possible different orderings as distinct solutions, use `itertools.permutations` instead:

```
>>> [c for c in itertools.permutations(numbers, number) if sum(c) == target_sum]
[(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0.1, 0.3, 0.6), (0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.1, 0.5, 0.4), (0.1, 0.6, 0.3), (0.1, 0.7, 0.2), (0.2, 0.1, 0.7), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0.2, 0.5, 0.3), (0.3, 0.1, 0.6), (0.3, 0.2, 0.5), (0.3, 0.5, 0.2), (0.4, 0.1, 0.5), (0.4, 0.5, 0.1), (0.5, 0.1, 0.4), (0.5, 0.2, 0.3), (0.5, 0.3, 0.2), (0.5, 0.4, 0.1), (0.6, 0.1, 0.3), (0.7, 0.1, 0.2)]
```

If you want to be able to use each element more than once, use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

```
>>> [c for c in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(numbers, number) if sum(c) == target_sum]
[(0.1, 0.1, 0.8), (0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0.1, 0.3, 0.6), (0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.2, 0.2, 0.6), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0.2, 0.4, 0.4), (0.3, 0.3, 0.4)]
```

If you want to use elements multiple times *and* get all the possible orderings, use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> [c for c in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=number) if sum(c) == target_sum]
[(0.1, 0.1, 0.8), (0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0.1, 0.3, 0.6), (0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (0.1, 0.5, 0.4), (0.1, 0.6, 0.3), (0.1, 0.7, 0.2), (0.1, 0.8, 0.1), (0.2, 0.1, 0.7), (0.2, 0.2, 0.6), (0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (0.2, 0.4, 0.4), (0.2, 0.5, 0.3), (0.2, 0.6, 0.2), (0.3, 0.1, 0.6), (0.3, 0.2, 0.5), (0.3, 0.3, 0.4), (0.3, 0.4, 0.3), (0.3, 0.5, 0.2), (0.4, 0.1, 0.5), (0.4, 0.2, 0.4), (0.4, 0.3, 0.3), (0.4, 0.4, 0.2), (0.4, 0.5, 0.1), (0.5, 0.1, 0.4), (0.5, 0.2, 0.3), (0.5, 0.3, 0.2), (0.5, 0.4, 0.1), (0.6, 0.1, 0.3), (0.6, 0.2, 0.2), (0.7, 0.1, 0.2), (0.8, 0.1, 0.1)]
```

Comment: Seems from ops examples that he wants `combinations_with_replacements`

Comment: On closer inspection I think it's actually `itertools.product`.  :)